# How to Like a Page-App?

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-like

i was wondering how I can implement the like button on one of my page apps (tabs).
The like should bring up a post on my timeline with headline, image and link to my page app.

If it's not possible I'll go for the share-dialog.

Thanks for your help.

g.
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

There is an option "like button" in facebook developpers. Inside this menu, you can create an url for the people to like your page. This url has to be pasted to your site, and it would work.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: cant find the "like button" link. Do you have a screenshot?